# Java variable type from string

Tags: java

this is my code

```
Class<?> clazz;
    try {
        clazz = Class.forName("classes.Pizza");
        Object p2 = clazz.newInstance();
        System.out.println(p2.test);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error is "test cannot be resolved or is not a field"
I want to get a string containing the class name and create a object with that type.. something like

```
String x = "Pizza"
x pizza1 = new x();
```

How do i do that ?

Comment: cast object to a specific type before you call a method on it.

Comment: Hint: what is the type of `p2` available for compiler? Does this type have `test` field?

Comment: i do not want to hardcode "(Pizza)" because the string X can contain another class name other than Pizza

Comment: @user3770536 Then how do you know, that "the other class name" has the field `test`? Or any other field you like to access?

Comment: `test` is a method or instance variable ... ??

Comment: test is a property.. public String test = "asd"; 
but i realize i can call the .toString() method on obj.. so i just override this method to get what i want
Thanks for help !

Comment: Where are you getting this `x` string from? It seems like you're trying to fix a bad solution to a problem instead of trying to find a better solution for that problem. The "proper" way to tackle this kind of problem would involve introducing a common interface with e.g. a `getTest()` method, and using polymorphism to allow for different implementations.

Comment: I have a project for school.
Basically i created a class Products and other classes (Pizza, Calzone, etc) that have different attributes and i want to export them into txt.
And on the import i want to get a attribute named Type which will help me determine what kind of object is that, pizza, calzone or etc to know what objects to create

Comment: That's a *much* better description for your problem. Clearly, you're not going to read or write *any* Java class to your text file: you only care about `Pizza` or `Calzone`. Those classes could implement a common interface with a method `void import(String fields)` and `String export()` to read their fields from a string or write fields to a string. They are responsible for correctly reading/writing *their own fields*, so you don't have to worry about that outside of those classes. I'm skipping over a lot of details here, but I feel like I'm already getting a bit off-topic...

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast Object to Pizza object:
This could cause ClassCastException too:

```
Class<?> clazz;
try {
    clazz = Class.forName("classes.Pizza");
    Object p2 = clazz.newInstance();
    System.out.println(((Pizza)p2).test);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT:**
You cant access the field `test`, when you dont know about it.
So you can access the field:

```
Class<?> clazz;
try {
    clazz = Class.forName("classes.Pizza");
    Object p2 = clazz.newInstance();
    /*System.out.println(((Pizza)p2).test);*/
    System.out.println(clazz.getDeclaredField("test").get(p2));
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Writed by javadoc only, not tested (and not sure about exception in this case)

Comment: yes. With cast it works.. but i want to create object according to the String x. I only have that string so i can't hardcode the cast to Pizza because that string can be another class

Comment: @user3770536 How will you be sure that class has a `test` field? What should happen if the class with name `x` doesn't have a `test` field (e.g. what if `x` equals `"java.lang.Object"`)?

Comment: It will throw an NoSuchFieldException @MattiasBuelens

Comment: @maskacovnik I know that's what *will* happen. I'm asking if that's what OP *wants* to happen. Sure, you can abuse reflection to get away with anything, but most of the time it's a band-aid solution for the wrong problem.